# Android - longPress is not performing any action

Tags: javascript, android, appium

I'm trying to long-press element with following code:

```
    .then(function () {
        var logoElement = driver.elementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageView[@index='0']");
        var action = new wd.TouchAction();
        action.longPress(logoElement,4000);
        action.perform();
        driver.performTouchAction(action);
    })
```

I think I went through all of the topics here and all I can find is that this method is deprecated and new one should be used. I spent hours trying to figure this out.

I know this element is valid cause when I click it, it works fine.

UiAutomator is showing it as long-clickable as well.

I'm getting: `Error: Invalid element or el field passed`

Appium v.1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

longPress with latest java-client version:

```
new TouchAction(driver).longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(logoElement))).release().perform();
```

If you want to control duration of press:

```
new TouchAction(driver).longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(logoElement)).withDuration(Duration.ofMillis(4000))).release().perform();
```

Comment: I'm new to Appium, so maybe I'm missing something basic, like driver version has to match, etc... @tcardoso